# Desktop Database with Server without installation

Tags: java, database, server, desktop, h2

i have Java-Application that growth a lot over the past month.
All configurations from the programm and all the logs are stored in .txt or .log files.

The programm should change now. The user could install the programm on his own pc but the programm itself should get all the configurations from a central server also write the logs into a central place.

the problem is that we can't install a software on the server, we just have file read/write access to some shares.

so i'm looking for a database that stores the database file on a server without a server installation.
this is new for me so i have some problems with the technics. i checked H2, but i just see a server mode and a embedded mode. i need something like a embedded mode with "external" filebase.

any suggestions for me ?

Comment: sqlite is the thing you are looking for.

Comment: embedded mode does accept a location to save the data.  What is missing?

Comment: now nothing, that info was missing and i didn't found that info on there website. thx, that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Jayan told me in a comment to my question
**embedded mode does accept a location to save the data**.

Comment: Please provide this as comment or edit the original question.

Answer (score 1):

[HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) can be embedded into a any program.